# NoMethodError in PasswordResetsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, update-attribute

Hartl tutorial Chapter 10.2.3

When I attempt to submit existing user email to generate the password reset token, it breaks on the 2nd `update_attribute` call in the User model:

[image: /Users/apple/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-12-05 at 5.05.49 PM.png]

The `reset_sent_at` column is present in the database, and I can write to it no problem from the console:

```
usr = User.find_by(name: 'locutius’)

usr.update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)

usr.reset_sent_at

Sat, 05 Dec 2015 22:27:27 UTC +00:00
```

but something about the context via the server is causing it to fall over.  Any debug clues greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't try to call `update_attribute` but `udpate_attribute`.

You just have a simple misspelling in there.

Comment: d’oh!  must’ve looked at that 20 times... thanks for the catch -- maybe it’s time for a proper rails IDE instead of vim